# Phonegap, Youtube, and Fancybox

Tags: jquery, cordova, youtube, fancybox

Ok, using phonegap I am trying to make a native app. I have quickly figured out that in order to load external data like: "youtube" videos...you have to add it to the "ExternalHosts" in the phonegap.plist...which I have done. (so that is not the issue).

The issue is that when I click on the video link it opens the fancybox and then automatically opens Safari instead of loading the video inside the fancybox Iframe???

Here is some code because I know everyone wants it:

```
<ul>
<li ><a href="http://youtube.com/watch?v=x3PD49AlMlc&feature=channel_video_title" class="iframe">Video Link</a></li>
</ul>

//Fancybox calls
$(".iframe").bind('tap', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'width'         : 680,
        'height'        : 495,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'iframe'
    });
```

});

Has anyone tried to do this before? This is for an iPad...I will eventually create it for android tablets as well.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your `PhoneGap.plist` set the property `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` to `YES`. This would show and play the video inside the PhoneGap application itself.

Also, you should first use the iframe code to embed the video. This is what we use to show videos. See, the official blog entry and http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html and https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters for more information.